# retrieving images for the Facebook post - singular published story API is deprecated error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve posts from my organization page using Facebook Graph API. My app is in development mode and page admin is an admin for the App I should have access to the page posts.

I first do

> https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/[MY PAGE ID]?fields=posts.limit(10)&access_token=[MY App token]

This works and gives me last 10 posts from the page. Each post has an ID in form PageId_PostId from which I retrieve PostId.  Then I do

> https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/[POST ID]?fields=images&access_token=[MY App token]

This works **most** of the time, but sometimes I get an error:  `"message":"(#12) singular published story API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher","type":"OAuthException"`

What's the reason for this and how to avoid it? 
Thank you!!!

Comment: `images` should not work at all, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/post doesn’t mention it, and in Graph API Explorer I get a debug message saying, _“The images field does not exist on the PagePost object.”_ I think you should be looking for the `attachments` instead. And you don’t need to make an individual request for each post, you can do that directly in one request: `page-id/posts?fields=message,attachments`

Comment: @04FS page-id/posts  doesn't work in dev mode

Comment: It should, as long as you have access to the page itself (i.e., app user has admin role on the page and manage_pages is granted) - and it does, quick test in GAE confirms.

Comment: ahh so many tokens... I was using app token but need to use user token